# SQL Update IDs for columns in the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm sure this is answered elsewhere, however I'm not sure how to search for this specific question.

Let's say I have 2 tables:

- `InputDataNames` with columns `[Prospect_Name], [Product_Name], [Market_Name]`
- `Entity` with columns `[EntityId], [Name], [EntityTypeId]`, where `[Name]` is used in the `InputDataNames` table.

Now suppose I want to create a table equal to `InputDataNames`, but instead of Names, fill in with IDs from the `Entity` table:

- `InputDataIDs` with columns `[Prospect_ID], [Product_ID], [Market_ID]`

Using the `InputDataNames` table to populate the appropriate combination of IDs, how can I join with the `Entity` table to get the desired effect?

Note: I know this is sloppy, just doing a little database cleanup.

Comment: where are prospectId ProductId and MarketId supposed to come from? neither table has these values.

Comment: The [EntityId] field. Say [Prospect_Name] = ProspectA, match that with the [Name] field in the *Entity* table, then get the [EntityID] for that row.

Comment: Use sub-queries to select the ID that corresponds to the name.

Comment: I can do this, but how do I join all three together to do it at one shot? SELECT DISTINCT E.Id , N.Name
FROM Entity E
JOIN InputDataNames N on N.Prospect_Name = E.Name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can join to the entity table three times. Assuming the EntityTypeId column  determines whether or not the entity is a prospect, product, or market, then you should include that column in the join.  If they are numbered 1,2,3:

```
select 
    pros.entityid, prod.entityid, mkt.entityid
from 
    inputdatanames id
inner join 
    entity pros on id.prospect_name = pros.name and pros.entitytypeid = 1
inner join 
    entity prod on id.product_name = prod.name and prod.entitytypeid = 2
inner join 
    entity mkt on id.market_name = mkt.name and mkt.entitytypeid = 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
insert  InputDataIDs
        (Prospect_ID, Product_ID, Market_ID)
select  Prospect.EntityID
,       Product.EntityID
,       Market.EntityID
from    InputDataNames
left join
        Entity Prospect
on      Prospect.EntityTypeId = 1 -- Type of prospect
        and Prospect.Name = InputDataNames.Prospect_Name
left join
        Entity Product
on      Product.EntityTypeId = 2 -- Type of product
        and Product.Name = InputDataNames.Product_Name
left join
        Entity Market
on      Market.EntityTypeId = 3 -- Type of market
        and Market.Name = InputDataNames.Market_Name
```